# no link with title, id or text 'Delete' found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I'm using rspec and I'm trying to test the DELETE method for the user's cars :

```
 describe "DELETE " do
    it "should delete a car" do
        #@car = Factory.create :car
        expect { click_link "Delete" }.to change{Car.count}.by(-1)
    end
end
```

when I run it i got this error:

```
CarsController DELETE  should delete a car
 Failure/Error: expect { click_link "Delete" }.to change{Car.count}.by(-1)
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no link with title, id or text 'Delete' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_link'
 # ./spec/controllers/car_controller_spec.rb:30:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/controllers/car_controller_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and I don't know why becuase I have this link on my index.html.erb:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', user_car_path(@user, car), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

but in my app it works

Answer (score 2):

Delete requests in rails get converted to a form which is why the element cannot be found.  You will also need to trigger the confirmation.

To click on the Delete:

```
find('a', :text => 'Delete').click
```

To accept the confirmation:

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

There was a Railscast on implementing the destroy method without JavaScript if you want to be able to use `click_link`

http://railscasts.com/episodes/77-destroy-without-javascript/

Comment: I replaced my rspec test but the prompt shows me     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "span"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Try `find('a', :text => 'Delete').click`